# Need help writing an expression for time extraction in Qlik

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am new to Qlik and my project requires me to create a time field of format `HH:MM (AM/PM)` from existing time field of format `HH:MM:SS (AM/PM)`.
I am having trouble finding the expression I should write in the data manager to make it happen.

Example:

Existing time: `12:42:23 PM`

Format needed: `12:42 PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression like this:

```
time( time#(SomeField, 'hh:mm:ss TT'), 'hh:mm TT') )
```

Im using [time#](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterpretationFunctions/time_hash.htm) function first to "tell" Qlik that the data in `SomeField` is in format `hh:mm:ss TT` and then wrapping the result in [time](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Time.htm) function to convert/display the result as time but passing the second (optional) parameter to specify the output format. In our case `hh:mm TT` (without `:ss`) part.

(If the second parameter for `time` function is not provided then Qlik will use the default time format, specified in the `TimeFormat` variable at the beginning at the script)

Example script:

```
RawData:
Load
  SomeField,
  time( time#(SomeField, 'hh:mm:ss TT'), 'hh:mm TT') as TransformedField
;
Load
  '12:42:23 PM' as SomeField
AutoGenerate(1)
;
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: understood thanx :)